# Is there a way to prevent an input.symbols list from performing calculations if the list isn't selected in pinescript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am getting the folkowing error-Compiled code contains too many tokens: 74569. The limit is 68000.

I have the following input.symbol list in my code.  Is there a way to prevent the script from performing calculations if the exchange isn't selected?  I am below the limit if only one list is in my code.

Also, does anyone know if it is possible to put this list in a separate indicator and call it into my main indicator?

```
if exchangeList == "COINBASE1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             //: set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Binance:WLDUSDT")  :input.symbol( "Bingx:ZRXUSDT.PS")                                                                       
    s01 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:1INCHBTC")  : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DASHBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MATICBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ACHUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:API3USD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AXSUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BTRSTUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CVCUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EGLDUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FLOWUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GSTUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:INJUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LQTYUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MLNUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ORCAUSD")
    s02 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AAVEBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOGEBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MKRBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ACSUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:APTUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BADGERUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:C98USD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CVXUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ELAUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FLRUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GTCUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:INVUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LRCUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MNDEUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ORNUSD")
    s03 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ADABTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOTBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SNXBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ADAUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ARBUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BALUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CBETHUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DAIUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ENJUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FORTHUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GUSDUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:IOTXUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LSETHUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MONAUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:OSMOUSD")
    s04 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALGOBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ENJBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SOLBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AERGOUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ARPAUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BANDUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CELRUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DARUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ENSUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FORTUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GYENUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:JASMYUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LTCUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MPLUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:OXTUSD")
    s05 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ANKRBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EOSBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:UNIBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AGLDUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ASMUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BATUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CGLDUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DASHUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EOSUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FOXUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:HBARUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:KAVAUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MAGICUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MSOLUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:PAXUSD")
    s06 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ATOMBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETCBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:WBTCBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AIOZUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ASTUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BCHUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CHZUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DESOUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ERNUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FXUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:HFTUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:KNCUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MANAUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MTLUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:PERPUSD")
    s07 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AVAXBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETHBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:XLMBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALCXUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ATAUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BICOUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CLVUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DEXTUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETCUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GALUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:HIGHUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:KRLUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MASKUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MUSEUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:PLAUSD")
    s08 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AXSBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FILBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:XTZBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALEPHUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ATOMUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BIGTIMEUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:COMPUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DIAUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETHUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GFIUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:HNTUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:KSMUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MATHUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:NCTUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:PLUUSD")
    s09 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BALBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GRTBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:YFIBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALGOUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AUCTIONUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BITUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:COTIUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DIMOUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EUROCUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GHSTUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:HOPRUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LCXUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MATICUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:NEARUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:PNGUSD")
    s10 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BATBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ICPBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZECBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALICEUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AUDIOUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BLURUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:COVALUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DNTUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FARMUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GLMUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ICPUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LDOUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MDTUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:NKNUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:POLSUSD")
    s11 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BCHBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LINKBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:00USD")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AMPUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AURORAUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BLZUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CROUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOGEUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FETUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GMTUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:IDEXUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LINKUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MEDIAUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:NMRUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:PONDUSD")
    s12 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CGLDBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LRCBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:1INCHUSD")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ANKRUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AVAXUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BNTUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CRVUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOTUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FIDAUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GNOUSD")  : set=="11" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ILVUSD")  : set=="12" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LITUSD")  : set=="13" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:METISUSD")  : set=="14" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:OCEANUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:POWRUSD")
else if exchangeList == "COINBASE2"
    s01 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:1INCHBTC")  : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DASHBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MATICBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ACHUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:API3USD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AXSUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BTRSTUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CVCUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EGLDUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FLOWUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:PRQUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:RNDRUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:STXUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:TVKUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:XLMUSD")
    s02 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AAVEBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOGEBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:MKRBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ACSUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:APTUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BADGERUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:C98USD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CVXUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ELAUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FLRUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:PUNDIXUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ROSEUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SUIUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:UMAUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:XRPUSD")
    s03 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ADABTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOTBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SNXBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ADAUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ARBUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BALUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CBETHUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DAIUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ENJUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FORTHUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:PYRUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:RPLUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SUKUUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:UNFIUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:XTZUSD")
    s04 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALGOBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ENJBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SOLBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AERGOUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ARPAUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BANDUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CELRUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DARUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ENSUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FORTUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:PYUSDUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SANDUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SUPERUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:UNIUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:XYOUSD")
    s05 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ANKRBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EOSBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:UNIBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AGLDUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ASMUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BATUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CGLDUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DASHUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EOSUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FOXUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:QIUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SEIUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SUSHIUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:USDTUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:YFIUSD")
    s06 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ATOMBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETCBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:WBTCBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AIOZUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ASTUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BCHUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CHZUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DESOUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ERNUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FXUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:QNTUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SHIBUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SWFTCUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:VARAUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZECUSD")
    s07 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AVAXBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETHBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:XLMBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALCXUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ATAUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BICOUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CLVUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DEXTUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETCUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GALUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BTCUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SHPINGUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SYLOUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:VETUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZENUSD")
    s08 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AXSBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FILBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:XTZBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALEPHUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ATOMUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BIGTIMEUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:COMPUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DIAUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ETHUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GFIUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:RADUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SKLUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SYNUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:VOXELUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZRXUSD")
    s09 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BALBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GRTBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:YFIBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALGOUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AUCTIONUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BITUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:COTIUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DIMOUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:EUROCUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GHSTUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:RAIUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SNTUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:TIAUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:VTHOUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZRXUSD")
    s10 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BATBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ICPBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZECBTC")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ALICEUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AUDIOUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BLURUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:COVALUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DNTUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FARMUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GLMUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:RAREUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SNXUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:TIMEUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:WAMPLUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZRXUSD")
    s11 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BCHBTC")    : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LINKBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:00USD")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AMPUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AURORAUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BLZUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CROUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOGEUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FETUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GMTUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:RARIUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SOLUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:TRACUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:WAXLUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZRXUSD")
    s12 := set=="1" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CGLDBTC")   : set=="2" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:LRCBTC")  : set=="3" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:1INCHUSD")  : set=="4" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:ANKRUSD")  : set=="5" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:AVAXUSD")  : set=="6" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:BNTUSD")  : set=="7" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:CRVUSD")  : set=="8" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:DOTUSD")  : set=="9" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:FIDAUSD")  : set=="10" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:GNOUSD")  : set=="16" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:RBNUSD")  : set=="17" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:SPAUSD")  : set=="18" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:TRBUSD")  : set=="19" ?input.symbol( "Coinbase:WBTCUSD")  :input.symbol( "Coinbase:ZRXUSD")
else
    s01 := na
    s02 := na
    s03 := na
    s04 := na
    s05 := na
    s06 := na
    s07 := na
    s08 := na
    s09 := na
    s10 := na
    s11 := na
    s12 := na
```